# How can I get all forest plots in a single PDF using the 'meta' package in R?

Tags: r, pdf, r-forestplot

I am using  the "meta" package in R. I have 170 studies and when I use

```
pdf("C:/xxx/xxx.pdf", width=12, height=60,onefile=T)
```

I can not see all of them. Is it possible to store all individual studies in a single pdf?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? It would be helpful to provide an answer.